# ffmpeg, need help to make small thumbnail slideshow video from long video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editing, video-encoding, ffmpeg-filters

With ffmpeg command, I am trying to create a small thumbnail slideshow video of a large video
by selecting one frame every 60 seconds and then combining those frames to make a video in a way that each selected frame would show for 2 seconds.
I am using this command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "D:/input-video-1.mkv" \
-vf "fps=(1/60),setpts=N/FR/TB,scale=-2:240,fps=(1/2)" -an -sn -dn -y "D:/output-3.mp4"
```

But when I play the output video, one frame takes the entire video and output video length is also incorrect.
Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: try this way: `select='not(mod(n,25*60))',scale=-2:240,setpts=0.005*PTS` ← 25fps*60sec

Comment: Thanks. It works but output video length not showing correctly when playing in video player like GOM player. Why 0.005 in setpts?

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов I am using: `ffmpeg.exe -i "input.mkv" -vf "select='not(mod(n,24*60))',setpts=0.005*PTS,scale=-2:240" -r 1/2 "output.mp4"`

Answer (score 0):

Using this for now because with fps filter I am able to use -skip_frame nokey which makes the command complete much faster.

```
ffmpeg.exe -skip_frame nokey -i "input.mkv" \
-vf "fps=(1/60),settb=24/60,setpts=N,scale=-2:240" -r 1/2 -an -sn -dn "output.mp4"
```

If I use select filter like below then I can't use -skip_frame nokey becasue then it outputs only 1 or 2 frames.

```
-vf "select='not(mod(n,24*60))',setpts=0.005*PTS"
```

I hope someone enlightens me about setting correct values for setpts and settb because currently I am not sure about these values but it works for now

Comment: with `-skip_frame nokey` options, input video has reduced amount of frames, so `select='not(mod(n,10)',setpts=0.004*PTS`

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов Yes. I understand. But why 0.004 in setpts? Please explain this. Thanks

Comment: If input is 2 hour video, 0.004 = 28 sec duration of slideshow, 0.006 = 42 sec, etc. Change it for your wish.

Comment: @БаярГончикжапов Ok. Understood. Thanks